# Python: Using np.where in nested lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of nested arrays and I am trying to keep all zero values as zero and change all values unequal to zero to 1.

My data has the following format:

```
'{1: array([[[[ 5.06708628e-04,  5.33716137e-03, -3.77568938e-03,\n          -2.69471575e-03, -3.64973691e-03]],\n\n        [[ 6.05128659e-04,  5.42070033e-03, -3.83635662e-03,\n          -2.78958871e-03, -4.86449576e-03]],\n\n        [[ 6.41131198e-04,  5.45152786e-03, -3.85338596e-03,\n          -2.81970593e-03, -5.87525996e-03]]],\n\n\n       [[[ 7.88254565e-04,  4.92610307e-03, -1.86573615e-03,\n          -4.20137119e-03, -7.40213614e-03]],\n\n        [[ 8.71656295e-04,  5.00274107e-03, -1.92285792e-03,\n          -4.28525112e-03, -8.31885450e-03]],\n\n        [[ 9.33441277e-04,  5.06267437e-03, -1.90095432e-03,\n          -4.28809264e-03, -1.58244563e-02]]],\n\n\n       [[[-1.10245243e-03,  2.29098671e-03, -1.73771006e-03,\n           1.35018158e-03, -1.99436478e-02]],\n\n        [[-1.07780823e-03,  2.43516030e-03, -1.68547436e-03,\n           1.48328329e-03, -3.89504271e-02]],\n\n        [[0,  2.53843796e-03, -1.59086307e-03,\n           1.56265997e-03, -5.75679788e-02]]],\n\n\n       [[[ 1.19994223e-04,  3.17201016e-03, -9.20324203e-04,\n          -2.49995088e-03, -1.42026841e-02]],\n\n        [[ 2.65921499e-04,  3.31247201e-03, -8.96504852e-04,\n          -2.55349687e-03, -2.78023413e-02]],\n\n        [[ 3.61086198e-04,  3.39958555e-03, -8.34447262e-04,\n          -2.54551718e-03, -4.10882068e-02]]],\n\n\n       [[[ 5.27987306e-03,  1.30243114e-03, -1.22174273e-03,\n          -6.58576360e-03,  5.62665945e-05]],\n\n        [[ 5.36035236e-03,  0, -1.28603803e-03,\n          -6.67022295e-03,  8.24979328e-06]],\n\n        [[ 5.38762144e-03,  1.39558737e-03, -1.30688733e-03,\n          -6.69850324e-03, -2.91436296e-05]]]])}'
```

I can use a for loop as follows:

```
for i in result[1][0][0][0]:
    print(np.where(np.abs(i)>0,1,0))
```

But I would prefer a way that replaces the value and keeps it in the original format and ideally doesn't need to use multiple for loops.

Comment: Does your example input have any value equal to 0.0 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

For a single 4D (or any dimension) array, simply use

```
my_array[my_array != 0] = 1
```

Then iterate over dict and process each array as above.